# only first FAQ element expands on click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create an FAQ list. The answer displays fine on first click but I want to be able to click on another question and have that answer expand and the other close. Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// hide all the answers
$('.faq li div').hide();
$('.faq li').click(function(){
var question = $(this);
var answer = $(this).find('div');
// if the faq isn't active
if(!$('.faq li').hasClass('active')) {
      answer.slideDown();
      $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
      question.addClass('active');
}
else { 
     answer.slideUp();
     question.removeClass('active');
}

 });



});
```

The CSS:

```
ul.faq {
list-style:none;
cursor:pointer;
z-index:1;

}

ul.faq li h3 {
background:#0A5C75 url(../images/faq-inactive.png) right no-repeat;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 50px 20px 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border:1px solid #fff;
}
ul.faq li.active h3 {
background:#0A5C75 url(../images/faq-active.png) right no-repeat;

}
ul.faq li div {
background:#FFFFFF;
margin:0px 10px 10px 10px;
padding:20px;
overflow:hidden;
/* added fixed width to stop the jerkyness*/
width:522px;
position:relative;
top:-10px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(63, 70, 76, 0.15), 0px 4px 4px rgba(63, 70, 76, 0.15);
}
```

and the HTML

```
<ul class="faq">
        <li>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut arcu magna, sodales vel dignissim pharetra, adipiscing sed orci?</a></h3>
            <div>Vivamus rutrum arcu sit amet dolor pulvinar dictum. Etiam porttitor leo eget velit volutpat quis ultricies urna ornare. Quisque ac ultrices est. Ut lobortis malesuada justo, sed blandit sapien bibendum et. Donec vel ante eu orci pellentesque dictum. Phasellus molestie egestas du</div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut arcu magna, sodales vel dignissim pharetra, adipiscing sed orci?</a></h3>
             <div>This is the answer to question 2</div></li>
         <li>
             <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut arcu magna, sodales vel dignissim pharetra, adipiscing sed orci?</a></h3>
             <div>This is the answer to question 3</div>
         </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/e3Bec/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/XGJXM/

Your code is fine only thing is use ==> `if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {` **instead of** `if(!$('.faq li').hasClass('active')) {` `:)` **Also** you don't need this in your first conditional check `question.addClass('active');`

Rest code should help, `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide all the answers
    $('.faq li div').hide();
    $('.faq li').click(function() {
        $('div').slideUp();
        var question = $(this);
        var answer = $(this).find('div');
        // if the faq isn't active
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            answer.slideDown();
            $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
            //question.addClass('active');

        }
        else {        
            answer.slideUp();
            question.removeClass('active');
        }

    });



});​
```

Comment: Using Firefox 13 in JSfiddle, this code produces a very strange behavior if elements are clicked in a "random" order, same strange behavior is in Chrome.

Comment: @limelights cooleos man - I tried in safari mac osx lion, cheers for comment though wats the behavior in firefox bruv, thanks again for comment `:)`

Comment: sometimes when you click on the elements in a "random" order, clicking stops working and is in need to two clicks to open! Could be fiddle screwing with me, as well! :)

Comment: Hiya @limelights try this bruv plz: http://jsfiddle.net/e3Bec/ should work normal as! `:))`

Comment: @limelights Cheers man anyhoo +1 to your answer as well, below which I will click now, :P have a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I could improve on your code a bit and produce the behavior and also shorten the code by a fair bit.

Notice, I skipped using your active class in order to show how it could be achieved.

[Here's a tinker.io for demo](https://tinker.io/7ca38/1) I tested it in FF13 and Chrome

```
$('.faq li div').hide();
$('.faq li').click(function(event) {

    var clickedQuestion = event.target;
    var answer = $(clickedQuestion).siblings('div');

    if($('ul.faq').find('div').is(':visible')){
        $('ul.faq').find('div').slideUp();      
    }
    answer.slideDown();

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I like that you are not sliding up the element if it is already visible.

Maybe move the .hide into css "display:none", no point waiting for the dom to load to hide them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.faq li').click(function(event){
    $(this).find('div').not(":visible").slideDown();
    $('.faq li div:visible').not($(this).find('div')).slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback guys. Very helpful. I just added in a line at the start to hide all the answers, otherwise I've used the above code, very clean. Cheers

    $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.faq li div').hide();
   $('.faq li').click(function(event){
    $(this).find('div').not(":visible").slideDown();
    $('.faq li div:visible').not($(this).find('div')).slideUp();
     });
    })

Comment: actually, just one other thing, this doesn't allow for me to click on the 'visible' answer + question to contract itself. How would I do this?

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry didn't see this earlier.  In the first line of the click function, just replace .not(":visible").slideDown() with .slideToggle()

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Accordion. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/